# Discord.js. How to do 2nd argument for images searches

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I recently watched [this guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFtTTCbGwYY&t=610s) video, and this is all fine and all, but at the end of the video he says he'll teach us how to do a second args for each image(for example: !baby Penguin, i dont know why I dont just do one word and search dogpile for baby penguin, I might do that depending on how complex this soulution is) but i have to do a update for earth day, so I dont have time to wait. Any insight you guys have will be most helpful. This is one of the search functions I have. If it makes any differnce, my goal is too make a function for subspecies and even mabye cartoons, drawings for each animal

```js
switch(args[0]) {
   case 'iCat':
    iCat(msg);

   break;
}   

function iCat(msg){

  var options = {
    url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "cat" + "cats",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "text/html",
        "User-Agent": "Chrome"
    }
  };
```

Even though this is probaly super easy for some, thanks for taking the time of day to respond

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to add, this is for javascript, althought you probs could've guessed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab all arguments and use them in a query like so:

```js
var options = { 
url: `http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=${args.join(" ")}`,
method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "text/html",
 "User-Agent": "Chrome"
}
```

Comment: actually since this a url you prob want to instead: `${encodeURI(args.join(" "))}`

Comment: Thanks @syntle, but I just used if statement. I'm sure your solution would fine, but I'm just more familar with if statements